# Replace line if specific word matches in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

if particular word in line matches then I want to read that whole line .
how can I do that.

like if

```
var str = "this is test sample msg \n this is second line \n  ";
```

line which contain 'sample' word will be return back.

how can I do this in javascript?

Comment: using indexOf("string"), you can check whether that string exists in the sentence or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "this is test sample msg \n this is second line \n third samples";
str.split("\n").filter(function(str) {
    return ~str.indexOf("sample")
});
//["this is test sample msg ", " third samples"]
```

Comment: could you explain the `!!~` ?

Comment: @JibiAbraham `~` turns `-1` into `0` which is a falsy value. `.indexOf` returns `-1` when the string is not found.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var line = "sample text", var str = "sample";
if(line.indexOf(sample) > 0){
//do something
}else{
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnLine(lines, str)
{
    var i, lines = lines.split("\n");

    for(i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
    {
        if(lines[i].indexOf(str) !== -1)
        {
            return lines[i];
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

To use:

```
returnLine("this is test sample msg \n this is second line \n ", "sample");
```